# How can I get a single value from jsonp php

Tags: php, json, jsonp

Please can anyone help me out, I've done an API Call and I need to get a single value from the response, as response comes with jsonp.

```
jsonp ({"statuscode":"025","RRR":"290007816182","status":"Payment Reference generated"})"
```

Comment: just to get RRR, status

Comment: Did you call this API from javascript or PHP

Comment: the API call is from PHP

Comment: I think this API is expecting to be called from javascript as it is returning a `jsonp()` is there a paramter for you to specify you want a JSON response instead?

Comment: Add a complete code so we could help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get response in a variable and use json_decode function like following :

```
 $response = '{"statuscode":"025","RRR":"290007816182","status":"Payment Reference generated"}';

 $result = json_decode($response);
 echo $result->statuscode;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $result->RRR;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $result->status;
```

Comment: the response shows me blank

Comment: and why this jsonp() ???  jsonp ({"statuscode":"025","RRR":"290007816182","status":"Payment Reference generated"})

Comment: can you give me your ftp access so i can check it or give me screenshot

Comment: Hi, you seem to understand JSON well enough, may I  suggest you research `JSONP` a bit now

Comment: let me share my code

Comment: I just got a response from CURL  using the API endpoint, but it comes with json( response here);

Comment: can you share full code ? what is api calling and what is response getting